# Bash: echo from command while it's executing

Tags: bash

I want to see the entire output (not just the return value) of a script while it's executing via bash, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh    
cmd="$(script.py $arg)"
```

script.py prints multiple lines while executing, but I'm unable to see them
in bash. Is there a way to maybe pipe the output to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will display each line "produced" by your script while it is running:

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < <(script.py $arg 2>&1)
```

it will also, as suggested in the post above, redirect stderr to stdout

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is being output to stderr.  Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh    
cmd="$(script.py $arg 2>&1)"
```